# fetch the unique data from the two table based on field in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join

I have one two table named *endeavor* and *endeavor_plan* with following schema.

```
endeavor
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('endeavor_id_seq'::regclass),
  code character varying(48) NOT NULL,
  display_name character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  active_plan_id integer,
  status character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A'::bpchar,
  methodology character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'W'::character varying,
  CONSTRAINT endeavor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk6725eec2d3c3a85d FOREIGN KEY (active_plan_id)
      REFERENCES public.endeavor_plan (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

endeavor_plan
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('endeavor_plan_id_seq'::regclass),
  creation_ts timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  status character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A'::bpchar,
  name character varying(128) NOT NULL,
  endeavor_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT endeavor_plan_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT endeavor_plan_endeavor_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (endeavor_id)
      REFERENCES public.endeavor (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

endeavor data:
[image: 1]

endeavor_plan data:
[image: 2]

I want output like this:

```
endeavor_id endeavor_plan_id
1           1
2           6
3           8
4           10
```

Query:

If I have active_plan_id in endeavor then return that against their endeavor_id
else I want the oldest creation_ts endeavor_plan_id against their endeavor_id who does not have "D" status.
any suggestions????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it:

```
select e.id endeavor_id, coalesce(active_plan_id ,ep.id) endeavor_plan_id
from endeavor e
cross join lateral
( select id
  from endeavor_plan ep
  where ep.endeavor_id = e.id
  and ep.status <> 'D'
  order by creation_ts
  limit 1 
) ep
```

I assumed active_plan_id is null if no value is provided.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42b8a991448bee62c2a924cb1faa5048)*

Comment: @ShashiMallah see the fiddle